# Is "mieux vivre avec..." considered as a sort of an urge?

Tags: grammaire, adverbes, comparatifs

If so, can it be translated into English as *Better live with...*?

(This [cover](http://www.lepoint.fr/html/lepoint/en_kiosque.jsp) is so brilliant that I have simply felt the *urge* to share it with you -- unlike my better self, who doesn't do pictures.)

[image]

Comment: It means “live better” (“have a better life”) and not “better live”, which would be “mieux vaut vivre” in French.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je suis d'accord.  Y a-t-il une façon d'exprimer “_mieux vaut vivre_” en utilisant l’impératif ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez So it means _live better_. A very nice urge. 'Twould be so great if everyone lived with these two guys... In spirit, of course.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: **mieux vaut vivre**, équivaut-elle à « Il vaut mieux vivre ... » ?

Comment: Oui les deux sont équivalents, mais pour un titre d'article, le premier est plus… *punchy*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je crois que [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=%20Better%20live%20with) donne de bons exemples de traduction de "*Better live  with...*", selon les circonstances d'emploi.

*EDIT (après affichage de la couverture)*

*Mieux vivre avec*, veut dire vivre en meilleure santé, avec un meilleur moral, avoir une vie meilleure grâce à la compagnie de ces deux philosophes (post-socratiques).

N.B. Philosophiquement, il faudrait ajouter "*dans la société*" pour ce qui concerne les philosophes cités, sinon il vaudrait mieux s'intéresser aux pré-socratiques.